# Open Pelican relative path in emacs org-mode

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode, pelican

I'm using [Pelican](http://blog.getpelican.com), a static site generator, to provide an html personal wiki or knowledge base using `.org` files as its base. Links to internal content in Pelican use the syntax `{filename}/path/to/file`. However, since I'm using emacs org-mode, I would also like to be able to follow such links to their relevant files in org-mode. I'm hoping that there is a simple function I could write which would allow org-mode to follow such a link and open the relevant file, without compromising Pelican's use of the internal link syntax. I suspect that this might be done by means of `org-add-link-type` and a function which parses the proper absolute path to the file. But my elisp-fu is weak, and I'm unsure of how to proceed. Help appreciated!

**Edit**: just to give an example, I might have a link like `[[file:{filename}/path/to/file.org]]` in an org file. Is there a way to get org to open the file by substituting (maybe via regexp?) an absolute file path for `{filename}`, but also wouldn't alter the original link so that Pelican can still process it correctly?

Comment: Is {filename} a literal string that is always the same?

Comment: `{filename}` is always the same, yes. You can see the info on internal linking [here](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.6.3/content.html#linking-to-internal-content) if you're interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(org-add-link-type
 "pelican"
 (lambda (path) (org-open-file path))
 ;; ; export
 (lambda (path desc backend)
   (cond
    ((eq backend 'html)
     (format "{filename}/%s" (file-relative-name path))))))
#+END_SRC
```

Link to internal content pelican:/Users/jkitchin/blogofile-jkitchin.github.com/_blog/blog.org

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh
pwd
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: /Users/jkitchin/blogofile-jkitchin.github.com/_blog
```

exports to:

```
<p>
Link to internal content {filename}/blog.org
</p>
```

Comment: Hmm. Thanks John. The trouble with this is that the link without `{filename}` will have to be an absolute link while the link with `{filename}` would not. For example, I might have in the org file a link like (I'm on OS X`) `[[pelican:/Users/Username/bin/pelican/content/path/to/file.org][click me]]` which would have to be changed to a relative path like `[[pelican:{filename}/path/to/file.org][click me]]`. Note that `/Users/Username/bin/pelican/content/` has been replaced by `{filename}`.

Comment: I edited the response to use a relative path. Is that what you need?

Comment: The pelican links open in org-mode properly but don't give the right path in the html document. Am I right that this proposal assumes that I'm using org to convert the files to html? If so that might be a problem since I've been letting pelican (with org_pandoc as a plugin) do the conversion work.

Comment: You are right I did assume you were using orgmode to generate the html. I don't know how org-pandoc works or if it can be customized.

Comment: I've decided that if I can ever get org-publish to work properly I'll go with something like the above solution. So thanks!

Comment: I do something in between with blogofile. See https://github.com/jkitchin/jmax/blob/master/user/blogofile.el for the idea. I export an org-heading to an html file with a yaml header that blogofile can render.

Answer (score 1):

Using the original answer by John Kitchen as a basis to build upon (along with  [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/7330/11934)), the best function I came up with is the following:

```
   (org-add-link-type
   "pelican"
   (lambda (path) (org-open-file path))
   ;; ; export
   (lambda (path desc backend)
     (cond
      ((eq backend 'org)
       (format "[[file:{filename}/%s][%s]]" path (or desc "")))
      ((eq backend 'html)
       (format "<a href=\"%s\">%s</a>" path (or desc "")))
      ((eq backend 'md)
       (format "[{filename}/%s](%s)" path (or desc ""))))))
```

Depending on the backend used for `org-publish` the function will provide relative links for org, html, or markdown.